# MySQL and Zeoslib: None of the dynamic libraries can be found or not loadable (libmysql.dll) on Windows 8

Tags: mysql, database, delphi, dll, zeos

I am working with MySQL server and Zeoslib with Delphi. My program can remotely connect to the MySQL database but not locally. However, it keeps raising the following error - "None of the dynamic libraries can found or not loadable..."

[image]

So, I searched my system for the dll file. It is found within the MySQL library folder and MySQL Workbench folder. As suggested by other websites, I copied the libmysql.dll into my application folder. Still, my program keeps raising this NOT FOUND error on my windows 8 system. Any idea?

**Update**

- 64Bit Test machine - 64Bit MySQL server, 32 Bit Application using 32bit Zeolibs component.
- 32Bit Development machine - 32Bit MySQL server, 32Bit Application using 32Bit Zeoslib component.

Comment: Are they in the same bitness as your application ?

Comment: @TLama MySQL is 64bit on the test machine and on the 32 bit development machine mysql is 32bit. Also, I believe Zeoslib is 32bit as well. All this works without any problem on my 32bit development machine, where everything is 32 bit.

Comment: Use SysInternal Process Monitor and check what happens when your app loads. You will see what and where your application is trying to load, and why it fails.

Comment: Try it with the 32-bit MySQL dll in your app's folder on the 64-bit machine.

Comment: @MikeSutton Great! It works and my program is actually able to run queries....Thank you for your help. I was actually planning on doing some major work to get this working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By simply copying libmysql.dll from 32Bit System and pasting it into 64bit system within the program folder, the program was able to connect to the database locally (localhost).